# programmatically getting custom node belonging to a term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-nodes

have searched google but cannot find anything specific . Intention is to get all Custom Node types that have been assigned a specific term of vocabulary . for example the follwoing is a db query to get custom node type.

`$query->condition('type', "news_article")->fields('n',array('nid'))->orderBy('created', 'DESC')->range(0,90);`

can the same query be modified to also add the  filter for term id .

One other related question is that how can (in PHP) we get the term id from the url of the pattern e.g `<drupal site>/taxonomy/term/2` .

any help appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for a list of node types or a list of nodes? For your second question, Drupal provides the `arg()` function to read the internal path (not aliased) of any page. For a taxonomy term page, the term id is `arg(2)`.

Comment: thank you for the commemt. yes have used arg(2) for getting the term id